# Unexpexted 404 in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

I really don't understand why node(express) just render index page and return 404 for other pages ("comproAffitto" in the example).

app.js

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var comproAffitto= require ('./routes/comproAffitto');

...
...

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/comproAffitto', comproAffitto);
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

routes/comproAffitto.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET comproAffitto page. */
router.get('/comproAffitto', function(req, res, next) {
console.log("dentro");
res.render('comproAffitto', { title: 'Exprrress' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

html href

```
<a href="/comproAffitto/" class ....
```

console log

```
GET /comproAffitto/ 404
```

where is the problem?

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constructing the path two times: `/comproAffitto/comproAffitto`.
You should remove one of them or here:

```
app.use('/', comproAffitto);
```

or there:

routes/comproAffitto.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET comproAffitto page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
console.log("dentro");
res.render('comproAffitto', { title: 'Exprrress' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

leaving `app.use('/comproAffitto', comproAffitto);`

Answer (score 0):

You defined `/comproAffitto/comproAffitto` instead of `/comproAffitto`

You would need to either change this:

```
app.use('/comproAffitto', comproAffitto);
```

to this:

```
app.use('/', comproAffitto);
```

or this:

```
router.get('/comproAffitto', function(req, res, next) {
```

to this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
```